# Should functional interfaces be called directly?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I built a few classes that implement functional interfaces so that they can be reused, these include Predicates, Functions, etc.

These work great when I pass a new instance into a collection stream, for example:

```
myList.stream().filter(new PrimeNumberPredicate())...
```

Today I found the usage of a predicate by creating and calling a predicate directly:

```
boolean result = new PrimeNumberPredicate().test(myData);
```

I find this code a bit verbose, and I'd like to ask if there is another way to write this so that I could do the test without explicitly calling test() on a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do either. The fun of functional interfaces is that you don't have to explicitly implement any particular interface, nor create useless objects. All you need is a method that does what you want and you can bend it to your functional will.

Define the predicate function staticly:

```
class PrimeNumbers {
    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then use it in a stream like so:

```
myList.stream().filter(PrimeNumbers::isPrime)...
```

Non-functional code like your co-worker's could skip instantiating an object and call the function directly:

```
boolean result = PrimeNumbers.isPrime(myData);
```

This has the advantage of letting you name the class and method naturally, rather than "predicate" or "test" or "apply".

Comment: I still have a bit concern if i am populating a class with many static methods, or having multiple classes with single static method. It seems like if a method does not need to access class state, and it can be a functional interface, it could be made public and static so that it can be reused. In a backend service where the majority of the classes are stateless, it seems reuse can be maximized by having lots of static methods... This kind of breaks the common OOP in java, is there any best practice on how far we should go with functional programming in java?

Comment: OOP isn't useful in and of itself. It's just a tool; sometimes it's helpful, sometimes it's superfluous. In C++ or Python, say, one could omit the classes and just have global functions. That's not possible in Java. Still, there's nothing wrong with having a bunch of static methods. It's not an anti-pattern or a code smell.

Comment: @y62wang functional programming did not introduce any fundamental change in that regard. Did you ever look into `java.lang.Math` or `java.util.Collections`? Classes containing a bunch of `static` methods exist since the beginning of Java.

Comment: I guess fundamentally there is nothing wrong with using static methods, my concern is mainly on coupling, ie, using a lot of globally available functions inside OO paradigm. Embedded static methods can be harder to mock and test. I also have a bit of concern with code organization and readability...

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, OOP is not always the right tool for the job. There's no need to involve OO when calculating prime numbers. Static functions are great, especially if they are *pure* functions whose return value only depends on their parameters, not on any external state. Coupling isn't better or worse with static methods. Either way you're using an extra class: you call it `PrimeNumberPredicate`, I call it `PrimeNumbers`. The coupling is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can declare `test` as a static method, and use a method reference when an actual `Predicate` is required:

```
public class PrimeNumberCheck {
   public static boolean test(BigInteger n) {...}
}

myList.stream().filter(PrimeNumberCheck::test)

boolean result = PrimeNumberCheck.test(myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing wrong with calling `test`, you could use an equally verbose method that uses streams:

```
boolean result = Stream.of(myData).anyMatch(new PrimeNumberPredicate());
```

You could also make a single instance of `PrimeNumberPredicate`, and reuse it instead of creating `new` one all the time:

```
class PrimeNumberPredicate {
    public static final PrimeNumberPredicate Instance = new PrimeNumberPredicate();
    ...
}
```

Now the call would look like this:

```
boolean result = Stream.of(myData).anyMatch(PrimeNumberPredicate.Instance);
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question,  honestly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate My only explanation to this is that you didn't really understand the question or my post, because of the three responses this one provide the most direct answer to the "is [there] another way to write this so that I could do the test without explicitly calling test()" question. Here is a quick [demo](https://ideone.com/2sQd6q) for you to see that it actually compiles.